# How does spring basic authentication works for subsequent requests after login via basic authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am implementing REST services using springMVC. Now i have added basic authentication entry point in my spring security file. But i don`t know that, Once user authenticated by passing credentials in Authorization header does he need to pass those credentials for all subsequent requests?

for example, 
I have two URLs:

```
1) localhost/apppName/login
   // Here user passes credentials in Authorization header. So, user authenticated successfully.

2) localhost/appName/getUsers/1
 //Here, client need to pass those credentials in Authorization header?
  if it is needed, then why spring kept prinicpal object in the SecurityContextHoder after authentication done via BasicAuthenitcationEntryPoint?
```

Clients of this services can be any thing like Android, java, .Net 
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually the browser caches the credentials

Comment: For subsequent requests, do i need to pass credentials?.

Answer (score 2):

Pure REST is *stateless*, which means that no client context is being stored on the server between requests. That means you need to send the `Authorization` header for each request.

You *don't* need to hit the login URL when using Basic auth, that's the point.

However, you *can* use sessions in combination with Basic auth, and in that case you should pass session cookie between requests. It may have  some performance advantage, but generally I would not recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But my idea is instead of session with basic auth i am asking to the client pass token in Authorization header after authenticated. now i want to combine token with Basic auth. How can i do this?